# Extract CKA_Value from Key or data Object in PKCS11

Tags: pkcs#11

I would like to read Key value from a KEY/Data object of PKCS11 into a local variable.
I observe that Key is stored in CKA_VALUE of Key object.
Which is the ideal function to be used to get this value to my local variable?

I have used C_GetAttributeValue it but doesn't help.

Please guide me.

Thanks
Harsha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private keys of assymmetric algorithms and symmetric keys usually can not be extracted from the hardware device. This is a protection measure. That's why you can't get the value.

There exist exceptions (some implementations allow you to add the key and explicitly mark it as not protected, in which case the key can be read later) but this reduces security and other user benefits, so this not popular.

Answer (score 0):

In some implementation, if you set the CKA.CKA_SENSITIVE to false, yes you can read the value.

Answer (score 0):

If CKA_EXTRACTABLE is set to CK_FALSE on a key then the value cannot be extracted using PKCS#11.

IF CKA_SENSITIVE is set to CK_TRUE then a key cannot be extracted in plain text.

However,

If CKA_EXTRACTABLE is CK_TRUE, and CKA_SENSITIVE is CK_FALSE the key can be extracted using CKA_VALUE.

If CKA_EXTRACTABLE is CK_TRUE, and CKA_SENSITIVE is CK_TRUE the key can be extracted by wrapping the key using C_WrapKey, then unwrapping the wrapped key outside the unit.